# Constructing objects from classes which are stored in the container

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public abstract static class Base {
    }

    public static class Derived1 extends Base {
    }

    public static class Derived2 extends Base {
    }

    public static <T> T createObject(Class<T> someClass) {
        T a = null;
        try {
            a = someClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived2 d2 = createObject(Derived2.class);   // here it works

        // here is some array with classes
        Class[] someClasses = new Class[] { Derived1.class, Derived2.class };
        // here is some list which should be filled with objects of these classes
        List<? extends Base> l = new ArrayList();
        // in this loop, the list should be filled with objects
        for(Class c : someClasses) {
            l.add(createObject<? extends Base>(c));   // ERROR: java: illegal start of expression
        }
    }
}
```

The error in the above code is on the line:

```
l.add(createObject<? extends Base>(c));   // ERROR: java: illegal start of expression
```

How to correctly construct the `for` loop and how to call method `createObject` correctly so the list `l` is filled with objects of classes in the array `someClasses`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Class[]` should be a `Class<? extends Base>[]`.  Alternately, use a `List<Class<? extends Base>>`, which won't cause a generics warning.

Comment: I don't think you can create a `Class<? extends Base>[]`. See [§15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) *"It is a compile-time error if the ClassOrInterfaceType does not denote a reifiable type"*

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with arrays. You can only create arrays whose component types are *reifiable types* because at runtime the JVM must do a type check when you put an element in (and if the element's type is different from the array's an `ArrayStoreException` is thrown). This means that you can only create an array of `Class` or `Class<?>`, and since you can't express the relation of the elements to `Class<Base>`, you'd have to perform unchecked casts on the items taken from the array.

The first *fix* is throwing arrays away and using a generic container for the source, like a `List<Class<? extends Base>>`

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Class<? extends Base>> src = new LinkedList<Class<? extends Base>>() {
        {
            add(Derived1.class);
            add(Derived2.class);
        }
    };

    List<Base> dst = new LinkedList<Base>();

    for (Class<? extends Base> c : src)
        dst.add(createObject(c));

}
```